# Git force push with IntelliJ IDE

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've searched the documentation and online also, but I can seem to find a way to do Git force push aka `git push --force` with *IntelliJ*, it is easy to do with the command line but how can you do it within the IDE itself?

Comment: Have a look on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#push , bullet point 5. Since you don't say which version of IntelliJ you have, I'm going to assume that page from the manual applies.

Comment: That dropdown item can't be clicked

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the Push window (Ctrl/cmd-shift-K), the **Push button has a down arrow** to reveal a dropdown option ‘**Force Push**’. This will perform at first a `--force-with-lease`, which if fails, will prompt a `--force` push.

[image]

If your branch is trying to push to master, ‘Force Push’ is grey. To enable force push to master, remove it from the list of protected branches in Preferences → Git:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the effort from JetBrains, but I really needed this out of the box :D

Comment: Thanks! Never know there is "Protected branches".